# Is there a way for MMC snap-ins to manage a remote computer in a different domain with no trust?

Tags: windows, domain, mmc

We have a Windows Server 2016 Standard (no Desktop) VM sitting in a different domain and network. I used sconfig through the VM console to add it to the domain and enable remote management. MMC management works when connecting from another server in the same domain/network.

While RDP is accessible from our management domain/network, it does not look like the MMC snap-ins can connect. It just gives us the error that we do not have permissions, as we are connecting from a different domain.

As the title asks, is there a way for us to remotely manage the server through MMC while on a different domain?

Comment: Edit: I confirmed that MMC works when accessing it from another server in the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create a user account in the target domain with the same username and password that you use to log in to your local machine.
2. Grant the new domain account the appropriate administrative permissions.
3. Run the MMC console and add whatever snap-ins you require, pointing them to the server in the remote domain.

As long as any firewalls between the computers are properly configured, the MMC snap-in will attempt to authenticate on the target domain using the credentials of your local account.  While the domain name won't match, the username and password will and your connection should be authorized.

Comment: Does this have to be a new user? I temporarily changed my user account (same username format) to use the same password for both domains. I am still getting the same error as before.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a new account, but the username and password must be identical in both domains.

Comment: If that is the case, then it did not work. The managing server is a Windows Server 2012 R2, while the target is a 2016. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @plat0pus No, that should not matter. What error do you get when connecting the MMC console to the remote server?

Comment: The error is "You do not have the correct permissions to open the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security console." The Windows Firewall is the particular MMC snap-in I was testing with. I just noticed that certain MMC snap-ins are working. I was able to look at the Certificates snap-in, but not allowed into Disk Management and limited access in Computer Management.

Comment: This could mean a few things: 1) Firewall(s) are preventing some necessary communications, 2) The account doesn't have permission to manage certain functions, or 3) Some of these functions aren't configured for remote management.  Based on the fact you seems to be able to do all of these things from an on-domain computer, I'd lean toward #1. However, it's clear that you've demonstrated the ability to connect via an MMC console from an off-domain computer, which is good.